# how to list resource offers from a particular mesos slave

Tags: mesos, marathon

Is there a way to figure out all the resource offers from a particular slave? To give you the context some of my slaves which have a specific tag attached to them are not making any offers though in mesos UI I see they are less than 50% loaded. I want to debug the root cause and for the same need a way to figure out what offers are flowing from slave to master to framework. Framework in my case is marathon.

Comment: In marathon log you can find offers that it receive from Mesos. Look for: [Insufficient resources for](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/95e606a40702bba0ec3101d030129a254afb2180/src/main/scala/mesosphere/mesos/TaskBuilder.scala#L56-L60)

Comment: I figured that out however couldn't figure out why offers from some slaves are not coming to marathon framework. I'm pretty sure those slaves have free resources since I can see in mesos logs that sufficient resources were recovered from them and the same can be verified by looking at number of tasks running on those slaves. Just wondering if there is a logic to keep circulating the top n offers to a framework x rather than circulating the complete list of available offers from different slaves.